# Faraday::RackBuilder methods

Tags: ruby, faraday

in order to use custom middlewares from faraday docs I see that I have to use the `use` method. In my use case my custom builder just add a jwt auth token in the header:

```
Faraday.new(url: wsconfig.base_url) do |builder|
  builder.use CustomMiddlewares::JwtAuthentication
  builder.request :url_encoded
  builder.response :json
  builder.adapter :net_http
end
```

**jwt_authentication.rb**

```
require 'jwt'

module CustomMiddlewares
  class JwtAuthentication < Faraday::Middleware
    def call(env)
      payload = RequestStore.store[:jwt_claims].to_h.merge({method: env.method, path: env.url.request_uri})
      token = jwt(payload)
      Rails.logger.debug { "      with token: #{token}" }
      env[:request_headers]["Authorization"] = "Token: #{token}"
      @app.call(env)
    rescue StandardError => e
      raise "problem in JwtAuthentication Middleware"
    end

    private

    def jwt(payload, expiration = 1.minute.from_now)
      payload = payload.dup
      payload['exp'] = expiration.to_i
      payload['iss'] = 'cgp'
      JWT.encode(payload, key, 'RS256')
    end

    def key
      OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(Rails.configuration.x.secrets.ws_config.jwt_private_key)
    end

  end
end
```

`CustomMiddlewares::JwtAuthentication` should only be used on request phase like `url_encoded` middleware which is adde by `request` method. I wonder why I cannot do the same with mine:

```
builder.request CustomMiddlewares::JwtAuthentication
```

I got:

`CustomMiddlewares::VerbosingPseudonymizationWs is not registered on Faraday::Request (Faraday::Error)`

Comment: Can you show us the code of your `JwtAuthentication` middleware? You should be able to say `builder.request CustomMiddlewares::JwtAuthentication`, but maybe something is wrong with your middleware? (Assuming you're using Faraday 0.8 or above.)

Comment: question edited. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `builder.request` you first need to register the middleware like this:

```
Faraday::Request.register_middleware jwt: -> { CustomMiddlewares::JwtAuthentication }
```

Afterwards you should be able to call `builder.request :jwt`. This is due to `Faraday::RackBuilder#request` essentially calling `Faraday::RackBuilder#use` with `Faraday::Request.lookup_middleware(key)` as the first parameter.

See https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb#L92
and https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb#L228

This also means that there is no difference between `builder.request :jwt` and `builder.use CustomMiddlewares::JwtAuthentication`.
The difference between a request and a response middleware is that the response middlewares should inherit from `Faraday::Response::Middleware` which makes sure that they only execute on the response (`on_complete`). See https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/master/lib/faraday/response.rb#L8

I.e., even when registering a middleware via `builder.request` it can still act on the response if it implements the `on_complete` callback. Conversely you do not execute any code for the response if you do not implement the callback.